# Can't figure out the format this file is expecting to read

Tags: regex, perl

I've got a block of perl that is supposed to read from a static file for an IRC hostmask, a privilege level and a comment. Between the Perl (which I'm a certified novice in) and regex I'm having some trouble creating the file.

```
sub read_users {
    @users = ();

    open CONFIG, "<", "users";
    while (my $line = <CONFIG>)
    {
        next if $line =~ /^\s*#/;
        my ($mask, $level, $comment) = split /\s+/, $line, 3;

        push @users, [$mask, $level];
    }
    close CONFIG;
}
```

The file currently reads:

```
<CONFIG>
irc.hostmask.goes.here 500 comment
```

That isn't working. I see where it mentions the word users and the regex omits whitespace. I've grumbled over it enough and tried various formulations with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each line of the file must be either:

- a comment (which is ignored), consisting of optional whitespace, a `#`, and arbitrary text
- a "mask", "level", and "comment", separated by whitespace, with no leading whitespace before the mask.  The mask and level cannot contain whitespace, though the comment can.

`<CONFIG>` is not a valid line; the expression `my $line = <CONFIG>` merely reads one line from the `CONFIG` filehandle and stores it in `$line`, and the `while` causes this to repeat until `<CONFIG>` returns a false value (usually `undef` at end-of-file).

Comment: Thanks, that helps. What is the meaning of users in the line:  

    open CONFIG, "<", "users";

Comment: @DanielTharp: `users` is the name of the file that the script will read from.

Comment: Worked perfect. There was no users file so I didn't have that little clue. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @DanielTharp: You should usually use something like: `my $usersfile = "users"; open CONFIG, "<", $usersfile or die "Failed to open $usersfile for reading";` (using the old style of file handle, or `open my $config, "<", $usersfile or die "Failed to open $usersfile for reading";` using the new style lexical file handles, which you'd refer to as `$config` in subsequent I/O operations).

Comment: To clarify, I'm pretty much inheriting this project and don't know much perl as it stands, but that's more readable to me, yes. Thanks for the advice.